# React change state from a template page

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a page template which renders json into react components like

```
id: 1,
type: "text_box"
```

This would then render tell the program to render a text box content. Inside this text box component I have a state like the one below:

```
const[error, setError] = useState(false);
```

In the onSubmission part of the template page I was wondering how I could grab the instance of the React component so I can change the state to true if there was an error. The code below provides the JSON that renders the component:

```
pageDetails.components[x].component
```

This code snippet above is from the onSubmit part of the template and contains JSON of all components on the page. So this outputs

```
{type: text_box, .....other fields}
```

I can't see from this data if I can change the state or not. Is there anyway I can use this data to change a state or is there a different better way to accomplish this. I can't share much code other than this but if more code is required I can look if I can oblige this request.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can include support for a `props` object within each of your component JSON properties whose contents contain the properties for things such as local state? This could be spread on each of your child "components"; inside your "component" you could then watch `props` and use that JSON property to control the local state of the component.

```
const[error, setError] = useState(props.error !== null ? props.error : false);
...
useEffect(() => {
    setError(props.error);
}, [props.error]);
...
```